# SQL - BigQuery - Using Group & MAX in several columns - Similar to a pivot table

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, max, greatest-n-per-group

How would you approach this via SQL? Let's take this example

```
| id | type | score_a | score_b | score_c | label_a | label_b | label_c |
|----|------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| 1  | A    | 0.9     |         |         | L1      |         |         |
| 1  | B    |         | 0.7     |         |         | L2      |         |
| 1  | B    |         | 0.2     |         |         | L3      |         |
| 1  | C    |         |         | 0.2     |         |         | L4      |
| 1  | C    |         |         | 0.18    |         |         | L5      |
| 1  | C    |         |         | 0.12    |         |         | L6      |
| 2  | A    | 0.6     |         |         | L1      |         |         |
| 2  | A    | 0.3     |         |         | L2      |         |         |
```

I want to return the max score per `type` in conjunction with the `label_X`, Almost, like a pivot table but with these custom column names. So the outcome of the above will be like:

```
| id | type | score_a | label_a | score_b | label_b | score_c | label_c |
|----|------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| 1  | A    | 0.9     | L1      | 0.7     | L2      | 0.2     | L4      |
| 2  | A    | 0.6     | L1      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
```

Something like this is wrong as it yields both results per `type` per `label`

```
SELECT id,
  MAX(score_a) as score_a,
  label_a,
  MAX(score_b) as score_b,
  label_b as label_b,
  MAX(score_c) as score_c,
  label_c
FROM sample_table 
GROUP BY id, label_a, label_b, label_c
```

Is there an easy way to do this via SQL, I'm doing it right now from BigQuery and tried also pivot table as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26291831) but still no luck on how to flatten these into one big row with several columns

Any other ideas?

**UPDATE**

Expanding on what [BGM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63162987/344220) mentioned about design; the source of this data is a table with the following form:

```
| id | type | label | score |
|----|------|-------|-------|
| 1  | A    | L1    | 0.9   |
| 1  | B    | L2    | 0.7   |
| 1  | B    | L3    | 0.2   |
| 1  | C    | L4    | 0.6   |
| 1  | C    | L5    | 0.2   |
```

That gets converted to a flattened state as depicted at the top of this question using a query like

```
 SELECT id,
      type,
      MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN score ELSE 0 END) as score_a,
      MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN score ELSE 0 END) as score_b,
      MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'C' THEN score ELSE 0 END) as score_c,
      MAX(CASE WHEN model_type = 'theme' THEN label_score ELSE 0 END) as 
      -- labels
      (CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN label ELSE '' END) as label_a,
      (CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN label ELSE '' END) as label_b,
      (CASE WHEN type = 'C' THEN label ELSE '' END) as label_c,
    FROM table
    GROUP id, label_a, label_b, label_c
```

Do you think the intermediate step is unnecessary to get to the final solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation. In Big Query, arrays come handy for this:

```
select
    id,
    max(score_a) score_a,
    array_agg(label_a order by score_a desc limit 1)[offset(0)] label_a,
    max(score_b) score_b,
    array_agg(label_b order by score_b desc limit 1)[offset(0)] label_b,
    max(score_c) score_c,
    array_agg(label_c order by score_c desc limit 1)[offset(0)] label_c
from mytable
group by id
```

Note: in terms of design, you should not have multiple columns to store the scores and labels per types; you already have a column that represents the types, so you should have just two columns for the store and type.

Comment: yes, we do have a table that stores the scores and labels per types, what I pasted on this question is a projection of that table that expands on top over that. Do you think using that as a base instead of this expanded version somehow eases the queries?

Comment: @maerick . . . You might ask a *new* question with the data that you are are starting with.  It is probably simpler to use.