# Big query PIVOT operator, how do I make it work when column data type is STRING and I cannot apply aggregate functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I was trying to understand and work on big query new pivot operator.
From this another post [How to Pivot table in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272514/how-to-pivot-table-in-bigquery), I understand how it works.
The example in google documentation that is mentioned about data having product, sales and quarter and how we get Pivoted data using query below.

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM Produce)
  PIVOT(SUM(sales) FOR quarter IN ('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'))

+---------+----+----+----+----+
| product | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
+---------+----+----+----+----+
| Apple   | 77 | 0  | 25 | 2  |
| Kale    | 51 | 23 | 45 | 3  |
+---------+----+----+----+----+
```

I am wondering what if I have to PIVOT a data for data example below using PIVOT operator where the sales data is  STRING column and had below data. This is just for an example. I cannot provide real time data here as its sensitive data.

```
+---------+-------+---------+
| product | sales | quarter |
+---------+-------+---------+
| Kale    | good  | Q1      |
| Kale    | bad   | Q2      |
| Kale    | good  | Q3      |
| Kale    | bad   | Q4      |
| Apple   | bad   | Q1      |
| Apple   | good  | Q2      |
| Apple   | bad   | Q3      |
| Apple   | good   | Q4     |
+---------+-------+---------+
```

And the output should be as below

```
+---------+------+-----+-----+----+
| product | Q1   | Q2  | Q3  | Q4 |
+---------+------+-----+-----+----+
| Apple   | bad  | good| bad | good|
| Kale    | good | bad | good| bad |
+---------+------+-----+-----+-----+
```

In this case sum will not work, neither casting will work. How should we use PIVOT operator in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try aggregate functions that work with strings. For example `MAX`:

```
with Produce AS (
  SELECT 'Kale' as product, 'good' as sales, 'Q1' as quarter UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 'bad', 'Q2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 'good', 'Q3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 'bad', 'Q4' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 'bad', 'Q1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 'good', 'Q2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 'bad', 'Q3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 'good', 'Q4')
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT product, sales, quarter FROM Produce)
  PIVOT(MAX(sales) FOR quarter IN ('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Consider below

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM Produce)
  PIVOT(STRING_AGG(sales) FOR quarter IN ('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'))
```

Comment: thank you. it works. I just didn't think of other aggregate functions:-(

Comment: hope you will recognize [big] difference in using max vs. string_agg in cases like yours :o)

Comment: yes I know the difference. In this example that I gave (just a generic one), both string_agg and max will work but when the data changes and I add and extra row for apple Q3 'Apple', 'good', 'Q3' UNION ALL", both Max and STRING_AGG doesn't work. Obviously this is a just what I am thinking and is not real time. Perhaps, count(sales) will make sense here.

Comment: not sure what you mean by `doesn't work`!  it definitely works for me! and produces `bad,good` result for Q3, while with max it produces just `good`