# Can we custom our field name by using function in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a view table and would like to custom one of my field name based on latest date. For example like this:

```
SELECT SUM(total_settlement) AS CONCAT('total_settlement_', CAST(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK) AS STRING))
FROM `xxx.dataset.table_source`
WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

However, I got an error in that field-aliasing part. Is it possible to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider much simpler solution

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
SELECT SUM(total_settlement) AS total_settlement_''' || REGEXP_REPLACE('' || DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK), '-', '_') || 
''' FROM `xxx.dataset.table_source` 
WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() - 7 AND CURRENT_DATE()
'''
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try for an alternative solution, first calculate SUM() and Coll name seperately then apply [PIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272514/how-to-pivot-table-in-bigquery) over the result.

**Note**: On BigQuery we can Column names with character ("-"), we need to replace it.

Your modified Query will be as

```
SELECT Sum_value , REGEXP_REPLACE(Coll_name , "-", "_") Coll_name FROM
SELECT SUM(total_settlement) AS Sum_value , CONCAT('total_settlement_', CAST(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK) AS STRING)) AS Coll_name
FROM `xxx.dataset.table_source`
WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE())
```

Output response will be

[image]

Then you can apply PIVOT as per reff given above.

Final result will be as

[image]

Comment: I can use this workaround, thank you Vibhor!