# Flatten audit table records into one combined record

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm working with a BigQuery database table that holds history changes to different fields as separate events in a history table.

For example, take a table that has two fields:

| Id | Food | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | Bacon | Red |
| 9 | Salad | Green |

Any changes to the values in this table would be output to a history table like:

History table

| Change date | id | Field name | Field Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 Jan 2022 | 6 | Food | Steak |
| 19 Jan 2022 | 9 | Color | Yellow |
| 21 Jan 2022 | 6 | Color | Blue |

How can I transform the 'history' table so that it flattens the change values into a single inherited view of change state as shown below?

Transformed table

| id | Date | Food | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 17 Jan 2022 | Steak | Red |
| 9 | 19 Jan 2022 | Salad | Yellow |
| 6 | 21 jan 2022 | Steak | Blue |

Comment: Output does not reconcile with data. There is no Salad and Red in the sample so why are they in output? Why would Steak associate with Blue since they don't have same date? How many possible FieldName values?

Comment: The process assumes that a person has changed the values in the core table, and that a record of the changes is output to the history table. For example, on the 17 Jan a person changed the 'Food' field value of record #6 from 'Bacon' to 'Steak'

Comment: You want to associate changed value with current data from other fields? So the current data no longer has Bacon and Green values?

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: If record 6 Color was changed to Blue, why would your output show Red? Most history or audit tracking utilities I've seen would record old value. http://allenbrowne.com/AppAuditCode.html

Answer (score 0):

This requires to first PIVOT history table data then join to current data table. I use Access SQL but maybe can adapt the following:

Query1:

```
TRANSFORM First(History.FieldValue) AS FirstOfFieldValue
SELECT History.ChangeDate, History.ID
FROM History
GROUP BY History.ChangeDate, History.ID
PIVOT History.FieldName;
```

Query2:

```
SELECT Data.ID, Query1.ChangeDate, 
    IIf([Query1].[Color] IS NULL, [Data].[Color], [Query1].[Color]) AS C, 
    IIf([Query1].[Food] IS NULL,[Data].[Food], [Query1].[Food]) AS F
FROM Query1 INNER JOIN Data ON Query1.ID = Data.ID;
```

Comment: I need a BigQuery based solution

Comment: I did say 'adapt'. Explore PIVOT in BigQuery. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272514/how-to-pivot-table-in-bigquery. Make an attempt, edit question to show. Questions with no effort to solve usually just get closed. At least I gave you something to explore.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you can use below code to get expected output.

```
SELECT h.id,h.DateofChange,
       MAX(IF(Field_name = "Food", Field_value, d.Food)) as Food ,
       MAX(IF(Field_name = "Color", Field_value, d.Color)) as Color 
FROM `project.dataset.history3` as h, `project.dataset.demo3` as d WHERE h.id=d.id
GROUP BY h.id,h.DateofChange
```

I am attaching screenshots of the result.

**Demo Table**

[image]

**History Table**

[image]

**Query Results**

[image]

Comment: This emulates PIVOT. If there really is only two fields (Food and Color) then this works nicely. If there are many more fields involved, it gets cumbersome.