# group by and aggregate from tall to wide data in bigquery sql

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I want to aggregate group by and change it from tall to wide data in bigquery, how do I do so? I have a lot of sources and here's a sample data.

Here's the table

| date | source | price | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | A | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-01-03 | A | 4 | 1 |
| 2022-01-04 | A | 4 | 1 |
| 2022-01-01 | B | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | B | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-01-03 | B | 3 | 1 |
| 2022-01-04 | B | 3 | 1 |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 2 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 | A | 2 | 2 |
| 2022-01-03 | A | 4 | 2 |
| 2022-01-04 | A | 4 | 2 |
| 2022-01-01 | B | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 | B | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-01-03 | B | 3 | 2 |
| 2022-01-04 | B | 3 | 2 |

into
fields of min from price from all source for group by id and min price per source group by id

| id | minPrice | minPriceSourceA | minPriceSourceB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.5 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 2.5 | 3 | 2 |

Here's my current code

```
with Amin as 
(
select 
id,source,
min(price) min price
from table
where source ="A"
group by 1,2
),
Bmin as
(
select 
id,source,
min(price) min price
from table
where source ="B"
group by 1,2
),


select
t1.id,t1.minprice,
Amin.minprice minPriceSourceA,
Bmin.minprice minPriceSourceB
from(
select 
id,source,
min(price) minprice
from table
group by 1,2) t1
left join Amin on t1.id=Amin.id
left join Bmin on t1.id=Bmin.id
```

The problem is I have over 100 sources and id, if I do query manually the code will be very long. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`PIVOT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator) to transpose rows into columns and get the `MIN` of a list of columns at once:

```sql
with sample as (
  select "2022-01-01" as date, "A" as source, 2 as price, "1" as id
  UNION ALL
  select "2022-01-02" as date, "A" as source, 1 as price, "1" as id
  UNION ALL
  select "2022-01-04" as date, "B" as source, 1 as price, "1" as id
  UNION ALL
  select "2022-01-04" as date, "A" as source, 2 as price, "2" as id
  UNION ALL
  select "2022-01-04" as date, "A" as source, 4 as price, "2" as id
  UNION ALL
  select "2022-01-04" as date, "B" as source, 3 as price, "2" as id
),
min_by_source as (
  SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT id, source, price FROM sample)
    PIVOT(MIN(price) AS minPrice FOR source IN ('A', 'B')) -- add here the others sources
),
min_global as (
  SELECT id, MIN(price) AS minPrice
  FROM sample
  GROUP BY id
)
SELECT * 
FROM min_global
JOIN min_by_source USING (id)
```

Output:

```
id  minPrice    minPrice_A  minPrice_B
1   1           1           1
2   2           2           3
```

Comment: hi this works, but the if source PIVOT(MIN(price) AS minPrice FOR source IN (items), for items here I tried using select distinct source from sample it won't work, do I have to type it manually and what if the source have spaces in between for example source A item

Comment: The `IN` clause in `PIVOT` do not allow dynamic values, so you cannot use a `SELECT` statement. An way to resolve this is use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to generate a dynamic query, this answer has an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67480414/3010548

Answer (score 0):

Consider below option

```
select * from (
  select * except(date), 
    avg(price) over(partition by id) avgPrice, 
    min(price) over(partition by id) minPrice 
  from your_table)
pivot (min(price) minPriceSource for source in ('A', 'B'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

> The problem is I have over 100 sources and id, if I do query manually the code will be very long. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Use below dynamic version

```
execute immediate (select '''
select * from (
  select * except(date), 
    avg(price) over(partition by id) avgPrice, 
    min(price) over(partition by id) minPrice 
  from your_table)
pivot (min(price) minPriceSource for source in (''' || string_agg(distinct '"' || source || '"') || '''))
'''
from your_table
)
```