# Pivot/Unpivot in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot-table, transpose

I have a requirement to change the structure of Product Hierarchy Bigquery table as below:
This should be done using Bigquery SQL

Current Table:

| salesorg | distr_chan | material | hier_lvl | prod_hier | txt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PH01 | 20 | 680483 | prodh1 | PH | Philippines |
| PH01 | 20 | 680483 | prodh2 | PHGR | Grocery |
| PH01 | 20 | 680483 | prodh3 | PHGRGR | Grocery |
| PH01 | 20 | 680483 | prodh4 | PHGRGR731 | Eden Mayo |
| PH01 | 20 | 680483 | prodh5 | PHGRGR731Q27 | Eden Mayo |
| PH01 | 20 | 680483 | prodh6 | PHGRGR731Q27P410 | Sandwich Spread |
| PH01 | 20 | 680483 | prodh7 | PHGRGR731Q27P410PI | Bottle |

Required Table

| salesorg | distr_chan | material | prodh1 | prodh2 | prodh3 | prodh4 | prodh5 | prodh6 | prodh7 | prodh1txt | prodh2txt | prodh3txt | prodh4txt | prodh5txt | prodh6txt | prodh7txt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PH01 | 20 | 680483 | PH | PHGR | PHGRGR | PHGRGR731 | PHGRGR731Q27 | PHGRGR731Q27P410 | PHGRGR731Q27P410PI | Philippines | Grocery | Grocery | Eden Mayo | Eden Mayo | Sandwich Spread | Bottle |

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272514/how-to-pivot-table-in-bigquery

Comment: I dont think so, as i dont want to aggregate any column. Also, i want prodh1, prodh2....prodh7 as the new column names instead of creating column1 and putting value as prodh1.
Hope I am able to explain the requirement here.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Consier below query:

```sql
SELECT h.*,
       txt_prodh1 AS prodh1txt,
       txt_prodh2 AS prodh2txt,
       txt_prodh3 AS prodh3txt,
       txt_prodh4 AS prodh4txt,
       txt_prodh5 AS prodh5txt,
       txt_prodh6 AS prodh6txt,
       txt_prodh7 AS prodh7txt,
  FROM (
    SELECT * EXCEPT(txt) FROM sample
  ) PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(prod_hier) FOR hier_lvl IN ('prodh1', 'prodh2', 'prodh3', 'prodh4', 'prodh5', 'prodh6', 'prodh7')) AS h
  JOIN (
    SELECT * EXCEPT(prod_hier) FROM sample
  ) PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(txt) txt FOR hier_lvl IN ('prodh1', 'prodh2', 'prodh3', 'prodh4', 'prodh5', 'prodh6', 'prodh7')) AS t
  USING (salesorg, distr_chan, material);
```

output will be:

[image]

**2.** (another option) Not exactly same as your exptected output, but can be an option.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(prod_hier, txt), STRUCT(prod_hier AS hier, txt) AS prod FROM sample
) PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(prod) FOR hier_lvl IN ('prodh1', 'prodh2', 'prodh3', 'prodh4', 'prodh5', 'prodh6', 'prodh7'));
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am going with approach 1 and getting the desired output. Any idea of how can i change the column name for the second set of columns ?

Comment: @VikasTiwari, I've updated the query to change column name. kindly check that out

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach

```
select * from your_table
pivot (
  any_value(prod_hier) prodh, any_value(txt) prodhtxt 
  for cast(replace(hier_lvl, 'prodh', '') as int64) in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the casting for hier_level is not happening and i get an error as:
Bad int64 value: hier1

Comment: per data sample in your question - you have `prodh1`, `prodh2`, ... `prodh7` as a values for `hier_lvl` column. Looks like your real values are different! so just adjust replace statement respectively !