# how do I pivot this on google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is the data that I am currently working with.

| x | y | a |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | LL |
| 5 | 2 | LL |
| 5 | 4 | LL |
| 3 | 4 | LL |
| 6 | 7 | RR |
| 8 | 7 | RR |
| 8 | 9 | RR |
| 6 | 9 | RR |

I am trying to pivot the table such that it becomes:

| x1 | x2 | y1 | y2 | a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 | 2 | 4 | LL |
| 6 | 8 | 7 | 9 | RR |

I've tried AGG and the PIVOT functions, but can't seem to get this to work, and this has to be done using onky Google BQ. The complete dataset is much larger, so I need a general solution.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this solution with pivot works for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272514/how-to-pivot-table-in-bigquery

Comment: Hoe many distinct values `x` and `y` have for each `a` ?

Answer (score 0):

Below should be good start for you

```
select * from (
  select * from 
  (select *, row_number() over(partition by a) pos from (select distinct x, a from your_table)) 
  full outer join 
  (select *, row_number() over(partition by a) pos from (select distinct y, a from your_table)) 
  using (a, pos)
)
pivot (any_value(x) as x, any_value(y) as y for pos in (1,2))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

you can build that query dynamically (so you will not need to explicitly specify count of unique values) and use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to run it - there are plenty examples of such technique here on SO!