# Is it valid to use sum(*) for all columns and group them by date time?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to get sum of columns values and group them by half year window, but number of columns too many, which I want to automate such painful things with sql logic. since we can do count(*) for table, can we do sum(*) for getting sum of each columns values in big query standard sql? based on my intuition, I came up my sql but it didn't produce expected output. Can anyone suggest possible workaround ont this?

**objective**:

I just want to get sum of each column values then group by id, year, and half-year.

**my attempt and reproducible data**

here is my input table schema and values (Note that for making this minimal example, I just used sql server), here is [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KYJ9yR0b)

here is my attempt:

```
with tb1(
    select res.*
    from (
        select distinct
            txn.user_id,
            extract(year from txn.purchase_date) as purch_yr,
            CASE 
                WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM txn.purchase_date) IN (1, 2) THEN 1 
                WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM txn.purchase_date) IN (3, 4) THEN 2
            END AS purch_period,
    
        from trans txn
        group by user_id, purch_yr, purch_period
    ) as res
)

tb2 as (
    select 
        *,
        sum(*)   -- intend to get sum of each columns
    from trans
    group by user_id, purch_yr, purch_period
)
select tb1.*, tb2.*
from tb1 left join tb2 on tb2.user_id=tb1.user_id
```

I intend to sum of each columns using `sum(*)` and group them by `user_id, purch_yr, purch_period` but above attempt didn't fetch any data though. The reason of doing this because I have so many columns and I need to do `sum(col1), ..., sum(coln)`. Above attempt didn't work.

**update- new attempt**:

this is my another attempt but I got null values as sum of columns values:

```
select res.*
from (
  select distinct
    purchase_dateuser_id,
    extract(year from purchase_datepurchase_date) as purch_yr,
    CASE
        WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM purchase_datepurchase_date) IN (1, 2) THEN 1 
        WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM purchase_datepurchase_date) IN (3, 4) THEN 2
    END AS purch_period,
    SUM(prod_ab_amt),
    SUM(prod_bf_amt),
    SUM(prod_gm_amt),
    SUM(catg_cg_amt),
    SUM(catg_dh_amt),
    SUM(catg_xy_amt),
    SUM(catg_mk_amt),
    SUM(brand_hk_amt),
    SUM(brand_hp_amt),
    SUM(brand_vm_amt)
  from trans
  group by user_id, purch_yr, purch_period
) as res
```

in this attempt, I end up with null values as sum of columns values, any better ideas on this?

**sql server solution from SO**

I found this solution but it is specific for sql server though:

```
select ',SUM(' + QUOTENAME(name) + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME(name)
from sys.columns sc
WHERE sc.object_id = OBJECT_ID('trans')
AND sc.name NOT IN ('user_id', 'purchase_date')
```

Can anyone suggest possible workaround on this? How can I do this either in big query standard sql or similar one?

**output**:

here is my final output that I want to produce in [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KYJ9yR0b):

Is there any way I can get my expected output table? any suggestion on above big query sql?

Comment: SQL can't do this automatically. You can write a stored procedure that queries `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get all the column names and generate all the `SUM()` expressions for them.

Comment: If you have so many similar columns it's probably a bad database schema. You should normalize it so they're in separate rows, not lots of columns.

Comment: Is your question about MySQL or Google BigQuery? There's no `sys.columns` in MySQL. Don't spam irrelevant tags.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your heads up. my question is in google bigquery, I was mimicking sql server solution to bigquery that why sys.columns was defined in sql server. How should I do normalization? Could you elaborate your thoughts from first two comments above and do you mind to show possible workaround in bigquery? How should I get my expected outputs in [expected outputs](https://dbfiddle.uk/KYJ9yR0b)? thank you

Comment: Instead of separate `prod_ab_amt`, `prod_bf_amt`, etc. columns, have two columns `type` and `amt`. `type` contains strings like `prod_ab`, `prod_bf`. Then you can use `SUM(amt) ... GROUP BY user_id, purchase_date, type`

Comment: @Barmar will you mind making solution (with comments) that produce my expected output so SO community might get benefits from your input? I am curious how should we do normalization and the points you mentioned above in bigquery standard sql. thank you

Comment: I don't know BigQuery, I can't write an answer for it. I'm suggesting an alternate approach that doesn't require dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Barmar I can cope with bigquery sql logic by myself. Could you suggest mysql or postgres or any sql solution that support your points above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your table so each type is in its own row, instead of distinct columns.

```
CREATE TABLE trans (
    user_id varchar(10),
    purchase_date DATE,
    amt_type VARCHAR(10), -- prod_ab, prod_bf, catg_c, etc.
    amt FLOAT
);
```

Then you can use a query like:

```
SELECT user_id, purchase_date, amt_type, SUM(amt) AS total_amt
FROM trans
GROUP BY user_id, purchase_date, amt_type
```

If you want to get all the sums in a single row for a user+date, you can use `PIVOT`. See [How to Pivot table in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272514/how-to-pivot-table-in-bigquery)

Comment: It’s not clear for me how to transform input table, you mentioned do normalization but in the answer seems redefine table schema; I can’t control input table schema. Could you help me with working solution if possible? I stuck in this question a while.

Comment: That is what normalization is, it's a redefinition of the schema.

Comment: thanks, [dbffile](https://dbfiddle.uk/79TYB_UR)