# Transpose column to row without any 'id' or key column based on row number

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, pivot

Hi I have table like this

| name | cat_type |
| --- | --- |
| coco | Dom |
| coky | Anggora |
| chee | Turk |
| eena | Persian |
| onaa | Dom |
| haina | Turk |
| haani | Dom |

I want to try to transform to this

| Dom | Anggora | Turk | Persian |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| coco | coky | chee | eena |
| onaa | null | haina | null |
| haani | null | null | null |

I have tried the following approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
PIVOT( STRING_AGG(name) FOR cat_type IN ('Dom','Anggora','Turk','Persian'))
```

But I didn't get what I want, as I got result like the following:

| Dom | Anggora | Turk | Persian |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| coco,onaa,haani | coky | chee,haina | eena |

Is there something wrong in my query?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Pivot table in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272514/how-to-pivot-table-in-bigquery)

Comment: i think it's different to my case?, my data is in string type and didn't need to SUM and need to show the null result

Comment: Assign row numbers, then you can pivot, like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/YebT8oFc).

Comment: I think I got the right result from @.lemon and @.PonderStibbons. Many many thanks!

Comment: So, what you want to select is really four independent lists (Dom, Anggora, Turk, Persian) and show them side by side. In other words: You select four columns, but the rows don't have a meaning. You could see 'coky' and 'chee' in a row just as well as 'coky' and 'haina' - you don't care. This is a very uncommon task for SQL.

Comment: yes that's true I don't care about the rows part, and it made me confused about how to solve it (because I don't have any id). Btw thanks a lot! @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem looks like a slightly variation of classical pivot. What you're missing is the column you're grouping by, which in your case is the row number.

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cat_type ORDER BY name) AS rn
    FROM my_table
)
SELECT *, 
FROM cte
PIVOT (STRING_AGG(name) FOR cat_type IN ('Dom','Anggora','Turk','Persian'))
```

Comment: it works! Thanks a lot for correction of my query