# How to pivot table without typing column name manually in Scheduled queries in google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, set, pivot, declare

I was trying to use pivot for x columns, I don't want to do it by typing manually. I try to used `DECLARE category STRING; SET category`  but it can’t work on **Scheduled queries in google BigQuery**,
Could anyone help me on that. For example, I have some data like below.

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-01' AS event_date, 'action_CN' AS category, 'A' AS user_id UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-01', 'action_EN', 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-02', 'action_JP', 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-02', 'action_KO', 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-02', 'action_OTHER', 'D' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-02', 'adventure_CN', 'D' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-02', 'action_CN', 'D' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-03', 'action_EN', 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-03', 'action_JP', 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-03', 'action_EN', 'C' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-03', 'action_JP', 'D' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-03', 'action_EN', 'D' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-03', 'action_JP', 'D' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-04', 'action_EN', 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-04', 'action_JP', 'C' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-05', 'action_EN', 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-05', 'action_JP', 'C' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-06', 'action_EN', 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-05-06', 'action_JP', 'C'
)
SELECT * FROM data;
```

I want a pivot table by user_id, count(distinct event_date) column by category to
look like this below.

| user_id | action_CN | action_EN | action_JP | action_KO | action_OTHER | adventure_CN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 4 | 1 |  |  |  |
| B |  | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| C |  | 1 | 3 |  |  |  |
| D | 1 | 1 | 2 |  | 1 | 1 |

Comment: There are many solutions to pivoting tables available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272514/how-to-pivot-table-in-bigquery

Comment: SQL doesn't permit dynamically named columns, to achieve that you *need* `dynamic sql` to achieve this. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dynamic_sql

Comment: see: https://towardsdatascience.com/pivot-and-scripting-in-bigquery-cb096ff0eca2