# Bigquery query turn table around

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have single table like that:

```
UserID    user_properties_key    user_properties_value(String) 
User1      email                     user_email@gmail.com 
           weight                      55
```

And I want to get result like that:

```
UserId           email           weight    
User1     user_email@gmail.com     55 
User2     user2_email@email.com    155
```

My current query looks:

```
SELECT
  T1.UserId as UserId,
  T1.user_properties_value AS email,
  T2.user_properties_value AS weight,
FROM (FLATTEN([database20160814], user_properties_key )) AS T1
JOIN 
(FLATTEN([database20160814], user_properties_key )) AS T2
ON
  T1.userId = T2.userId
WHERE
  T1.user_properties_key="email"
  AND T2.user_properties_key="weight"
GROUP BY
  V0,
  V1,
  V2
```

If I'm trying to get more fields, query doesn't work or takes a long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT
  UserId,
  MAX(IF(user_properties.user_properties_key="email", user_properties.user_properties_value, NULL)) AS email,
  MAX(IF(user_properties.user_properties_key="weight", user_properties.user_properties_value, NULL)) AS weight
FROM [YourTable] 
GROUP BY UserId
```

OR

```
SELECT
  UserId,
  MAX(IF(user_properties.user_properties_key="email", user_properties.user_properties_value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS email,
  MAX(IF(user_properties.user_properties_key="weight", user_properties.user_properties_value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS weight
FROM [YourTable]
```

It is not clear from your question, so I assumed your table is as below

[image]

See also [Pivot Repeated fields in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33769831/5221944)

Comment: Thanks. It works! =) But i have one problem, one user can have many values(how result i have resul in field 'weight' Optional(32) or similar,and how i can get last value for this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Add specific example to you question otherwise it is not clear enough

Comment: I constantly update the data. How can i get last recorded value?

Comment: it is still not clear to me what exactly your `new question` is! i recommend you to ask new question and provide all relevant details there. i will be more than happy to try to answer new one

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly known as a pivot table operation. A previous question and answer give an example: [How to simulate a pivot table with BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414609/how-to-simulate-a-pivot-table-with-bigquery)

If you are using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/), some of the functions and syntax in the example would need to be changed, but the principle is the same.